# Why can a C/C++ function with preprocessed parameters link correctly only if defined in the header file?

Tags: c++, cmake, c-preprocessor, linker-errors, clion

I'm working with CLion (using CMake) in a project that involves an external library that redefines types depending on the definition of a macro.  For instance, if the flag macro is defined, then the struct type `MyType2D` is replaced by `MyType3D`.  I also have two files, `A.h` and `A.cpp`, where the header file holds a homonym class with two function declarations: `f1` and `f2`.  The difference between `f1` and `f2` is that `f1` has parameters whose types are unmodified by the preprocessor, and `f2` has parameters whose types are either `MyType3D` or `MyType2D`, depending on whether the flag macro is defined or not.

Now, when building the project, in the case of the flag macro not being defined, everything compiles, links, and executes correctly.  The problem occurs when the flag macro is defined, and then the parameter types in `f2` are switched to `MyType3D`.  In this case, when I build the project, compilation succeeds, but linking fails with the error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "A::f2(MyType3D const*)", referenced from:
      _main in main_3d.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note that during compilation, the object file `A.o` is produced as I have included it together with `main_3d.cpp` in the list of sources in CMake.  I have also verified this because the other function, `f1`, is not throwing any link error, and I happen to call it before calling `f2`.

However, this is what I can't understand: if I *move the definition* of `f1` from `A.cpp` to `A.h`, having the flag macro defined, the code compiles and runs as expected.  In my attempt to fix/understand this, I have done the following:

```cpp
// ...
#ifdef FlagMacro
    void f1( MyType3D const* var );
#else
    void f1( MyType2D const* var );
#endif
// ...
```

in both the `A.h` and `A.cpp` (with the appropriate function definition in the source file), but the error persists during linking with the exact same message.

My question is: why should I define the function in the header file (as part of the class `A`) when the preprocessor is used to changed the types of the parameters of the function?

Comment: There are a few things that are unclear about your explanation. Instead of just explaining in words which can be ambiguous, please provide a simple [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Instead of attempting to describe the code, please try to create a [mcve] to show us. There's some ambiguity between `f1` and `f2` which would be much clearer with actual code.

Comment: Ok.  Let me put together a minimal verifiable example.  I tried to explain it with words because this is just a very small portion of a very large project.  I'll try to replicate the behavior with the requested example.

Comment: Please do, this seems like an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), but without the actual code it's hard to say for sure.  You just might answer your own question by the time you produce an [mcve].

Comment: Where do you define `FlagMacro`? If I understand you correctly, you are assuming that `A.cpp` will be recompiled if the FlagMacro changes, but that can only happen if the file in which FlagMacro is defined is listed as a dependency of `A.cpp`. The way you usually get into trouble with this is putting `-DFlagMacro` on the command-line, making it difficult for the build system to know what it needs to rebuild. Don't play this particular game. There is a reason C++ has function overloading. Put both versions in the library and let the linker choose the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the `FlagMacro` was not defined at the time of compiling `A.cpp` into `A.o`.  Even though `FlagMacro` was set in an external header file (e.g. `p4est_to_p8est.h`) included in my `main_3d.cpp`, which also included `A.h`, the `A.cpp` was not able to see `FlagMacro` because I didn't have an explicit `#include p4est_to_p8est.h` in `A.h`.